# Why can't I download a .jar file using Webclient

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make a simple Minecraft Mod installer and whenever I DownloadString something that is a .jar and try to DownloadFile it, it says that its illegal path. Is there a way around it or does it just accept .txt .exe along that.

```
var Mod = wc.DownloadString("Link to download that is .jar");

wc.DownloadFile(Mod, @"C:\Users\" + Environment.UserName + @"\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\mods\Mod.jar");
```

That's the code I'm currently using worked fine for me when I was using .exe and .txt files but doesn't seem to work on .jar. Any work arounds?

Comment: Hi VWWE, There's `Path.Combine` instead of concatenating string with `+`, and also there's `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData)` instead of building it yourself with the username

Comment: Can you try a path without a folder that contains a dot `.minecraft` and tell us your results?

Comment: Also, knowing who `wc` is would help. please look at [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @PabloRecalde Yea I tried a folder without .minecraft and got the same result. And wc is webclient `WebClient wc = new WebClient();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `DownloadFile` method documentation says

> Downloads the resource with the specified URI to a local file. C#
>
> ```
> public void DownloadFile (Uri address, string fileName);
> ```
>
> **address:Uri**
>
> The URI specified as a String, from which to download data.
>
> **fileName:String**
>
> The name of the local file that is to receive the data.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloadfile?view=net-6.0

But in your example looks like you're first downloading the link as a string and then calling `DownloadFile` with that instead of the original Uri.

i.e. looks like you should be doing

```
wc.DownloadFile("Link to download that is .jar", Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), ".minecraft\mods\Mod.jar"));
```

Comment: The `Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData)` doesn't work for me because it shows `DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\rwnod\AppData\Local\.minecraft\mods\Mod.jar'.
` when minecraft is located at `C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft`

Comment: I figured it out it's `wc.DownloadFile("Download Link", @"C:\Users\" + Environment.UserName + @"\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\mods\test.jar");` thanks for the help anyways never knew you had to just use DownloadFile

Comment: Ok then there's `Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData` that I think will point to the `Roaming` folder.